# Как проверить, что сокет подключен?

Tags: asp.net, windows, сокет

Вот, к примеру, я подключаюсь к серверу:

```
TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();
Socket socket;

Client.Connetc("127.0.0.1", 1200);
socket = Client.Client;
```

Теперь как проверить, что сокет удачно подключен. К примеру, чтоб было так

```
if (Сокет успешно подключен)
{
    int i = 1;
}
else {
    int a = 0;
}
```

Comment: Какая система программирования (ОС, язык) Вас интересует ?

В большинстве случаев, если Connect() выполнен успешно, то socket удачно подключен.

Comment: Если ничего не вернуло ошибку, то скорее всего все подключено с "этой стороны". А проверить, что подключение действительно установлено - нужно отправить данные и получить ответ (если он нужен).

Comment: Windows, ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

Один индус из Лондона приводит [в своем блоге](http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-check-whether-socket-is-still.html) вот такой рецепт проверки подключения сокета в произвольный момент времени. У класса Socket имеется булевское свойство Connected, которое отражает факт подключения в ходе последней операции с удаленным узлом (возможно, выполненной давно). Метод проверки подключения по факту заключается в пинговании сокета:

```
public static bool IsSocketStillConnected(Socket socket)
{
    bool connected = true;
    bool blockingState = socket.Blocking;
    try
    {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1];
        socket.Blocking = false;
        socket.Send(tmp, 0, 0);
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        connected = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        socket.Blocking = blockingState;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Использоваться вышеприведенная функция может, например, так:

```
if (IsSocketStillConnected(mySocket))
{
    mySocket.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то надо определить поточнее, что значит "сокет подключен" ? В данный момент доступно чтение, запись или и то и  другое ? 

Как известно, есть вызов shutdown(int sockfd, int how);

     If how is  SHUT_RD,
       further  receptions  will  be  disallowed.   If how is SHUT_WR, further
       transmissions will be disallowed.  If how is SHUT_RDWR, further  recep‐
       tions and transmissions will be disallowed.